# Error while running iPhone App Help - __NSCFConstantString error meaning

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, error-handling

Could someone please tell me what this means:

```
2013-02-08 11:19:49.394 xxxxx[10545:907] set selected tab with tag 3
2013-02-08 11:19:49.560 xxxxx[10545:907] did select item
2013-02-08 11:19:49.562 xxxxx[10545:907] tab clicked
2013-02-08 11:19:49.566 xxxxx[10545:907] will show view controller MoreViewController
2013-02-08 11:19:49.567 xxxxx[10545:907] will show other VC

2013-02-08 11:19:49.579 xxxxx[10545:907] -[__NSCFConstantString offImage]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x21994c
2013-02-08 11:19:49.580 xxxxx[10545:907] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFConstantString offImage]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x21994c'
```

I just tried modifying some code, however the modifications did not work. So pressed z and undid everything I modified, but now I get this error.

Comment: you are probably calling a method for an object that was deallocated/released, and its memory space zone now is used by a new (different) object/instance that doesn't implement that method: you have a "Zombie"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "unrecognized selector sent to instance" error always means one thing: you are calling a method on an instance that does not support it. In this particular case, you have a line in your code that looks like this:

```
[someObject offImage];
```

On this line, `someObject` is an instance of string, which does not have an `offImage` method.

This problem could be caused by passing an object of a wrong type to some other method:

```
[someTarget objectWithOffImage:@"Hello"];
```

The method could be expecting an object that responds to `offImage`, but you are passing it a string.

Finally, you may be trying to invoke a method in a *category*, but you forgot to import the header file for the category.

Comment: Hmm, that's very strange. I am calling [item offImage] here:

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        //Set cell style
    }
    TabBarItem *item = _moreItems[indexPath.row];
    cell.imageView.image=[item offImage];
 cell.textLabel.text = item.title;
    return cell;

So the instance doesn't support offImage?

Comment: @SulaimanMajeed This means that `_moreItems[indexPath.row]` is pointing to a string object. This could happen when value of `indexPath.row` is greater than the size of the array, or when the array has a dangling pointer (i.e. something that used to point to an object that has since been de-allocated, and the memory for which has been reused for some other object, in this case, for a constant string).

Comment: I found that _moreItems[indexPath.row] was pointing to a location in memory that was invalid. I am still unsure of why there was a dangling pointer. I am trying to find out where the dangling pointer originated from. You helped me find the source of my error. Thank you for your help and clear answer!

Answer (score 0):

You are sending the message `-offImage` to an instance of `NSString` which does not have a method with that name. Alter your code so that `-offImage` is sent to the right kind of object